# Рассчитать уровень размытия для накладываемой картинки в зависимости от её размера, с учётом диапазонов указанных значений

Tags: алгоритм, математика, изображения, обработка-изображений, blur

Пишу скрипт, который накладывает множество клипартов (маленьких картинок) на одно большое изображение. Размеры (ширина) накладываемых клипартов могут быть случайными, например, "от 20 до 100 пикселей". В качестве дополнительного эффекта добавил для каждого клипарта размытие (blur), уровень которого также указывается в диапазоне, например, "от 2.00 до 8.00" и применяется в случайном порядке. С этим проблем нет, всё работает прекрасно, клипарты добавляются рандомного размера, с рандомным размытием...

Теперь я хочу сделать так, чтобы чем "меньше текущий размер клипарта" (в цикле программы), тем "больше его нужно размыть", причём необходимо учитывать два указанных диапазона значений: в пикселях "от 20 до 100" и уровня размытия "от 2.00 до 8.00".

Например:

1. Если "ширина клипарта" оказалась равной 100 пикселей, то нужно применить размытие 2 (минимальное).
2. Если "ширина клипарта" оказалась равной 20 пикселей, то нужно применить размытие 8 (максимальное).
3. Как я понимаю, если "ширина клипарта" оказалась равной 60 пикселей (это есть среднее значение из диапазона размера клипарта = (100+20)/2 = 60 ), то для этого размера нужно применить "размытие" равное 5 ( среднее значение из диапазона размытия (8+2)/2 = 5 ).

Я не пойму, как правильно **расчитать "нужное размытие"** от 2.00 до 8.00 **для любого размера клипарта** из диапазона от 20 до 100?

Далее я пытаюсь получить "коэфициент" (2/5)="0.4", после чего пытаюсь умножить его на "размер клипарта", но если я расчитываю размытие по формуле 0.4*100 (100 - это максимальный размер клипарта), то получается размытие аж 40 (вместо размытия 2), а для минимального размера клипарта 20: (0.4*20)="размытие 8" (тут получается правильно).

В математике я вообще плохо соображаю, методом тыка я написал расчёты, которые дают мне почти нужный результат, но они настолько неадекватные и плохо имеют связь с реальностью, что я даже боюсь их здесь описывать, чтобы за глупость меня не забили палками. Да и чтобы не сбивать с толку.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если диапазон `[a, b]` надо спроецировать на диапазон `[c, d]`, то соответствующая формула будет выглядеть так

```
f(x) = (x - a) * (d - c) / (b - a) + c
```

Формула для ваших значений получается такая

```
размытие = 
  = (размер - 20) * (8 - 2) / (100 - 20) + 2 = 
  = (размер - 20) * 3 / 40 + 2 =
  = размер * 0.075 + 0.5
```

P.S. Однако эта вариант для большего размытия при большем размере, а вам надо наоборот. Исходная формула прекрасно сработает и "наоборот", если поменять местами концы целевого диапазона. Т.е. проецируем `[20, 100]` на `[8, 2]`

```
размытие = 
  = (размер - 20) * (2 - 8) / (100 - 20) + 8 = 
  = (размер - 20) * -3 / 40 + 8 =
  = 9.5 - размер * 0.075
```

Comment: Так, отлично! Это то, что мне нужно. Вот только у меня ещё вопрос... Я вот сейчас считаю по формуле: ("20" - 20) * (8 - 2) / (100 - 20) + 2 = "размытие 2", если подставить в качестве размера "100", то "размытие получится 8", то есть то что мне нужно, но только наоборот. А как переписать формулу, чтобы "размер 20" давал "размытие не 2, а наоборот 8". Первая версия написанной вами формулы мне тоже подходит - это позволит сделать "чем больше клипарт, тем сильнее размытие".

Comment: Во, я практически методом тыка выяснил, как это сделать (**инвертировать результат**): (20 - "20") * (2 - 8) / (20 - 100) + 8 = "размытие 8", а для размера "100": (20 - "100") * (2 - 8) / (20 - 100) + 8 = "размытие 2". Надеюсь, что это правильное и изящное решение. Благодарю вас за помощь ещё раз!

Comment: @Василий Пупкин: Сработает та же исходная общая формула. Надо только в качестве `[c, d]` взять `[8, 2]`, а не `[2, 8]`.

Comment: Отлично, первая и вторая (инвертированная) версия расчёта в вашем основном ответе работает прекрасно. Коротко, понятно, чётко и изящно! Ну и ещё, если позволите, хочу поинтересоваться, с какой "математической тематикой" связаны эти расчёты, то есть какую вы можете порекомендовать почитать литературу, чтобы мне в этом разбираться (часто сталкиваюсь с решением задач такого рода)? Я чувствую, что это алгерба 5-го класса, но я в школе учиться вообще не любил и списывал постоянно, думать никак не хотел :)

Comment: @Василий Пупкин: Хм.. Простейшие формулы можно обосновать сотнями разных способов, и выбрать из них лучший трудно. Для меня "роднее" геометрическая интерпретация: перед вами ни что иное, как уравнение прямой вида `y(x) = kx + b`, проходящей через точки `(20, 8)` и `(100, 2)`.